# yii: CDbCriteria->mergeWith returns null

Tags: php, sql, yii

I have the following code:

```
     if ($query):
        $query_c = new CDbCriteria;
        $query_c->alias = 'P';
        $query_c->compare('name', $query, true, 'AND');
        $query_c->compare('description', $query, true, 'OR');
    endif;

    if ($category):
        $join = new CDbCriteria;
        $join->alias = 'P';
        $join->join='LEFT JOIN product_x_category as P_x_c ON P.id = P_x_c.product_id';

        $join->compare('P_x_c.category_id', '='.Category::model()->find('path=?', array($category))->id);
    endif;

    if ($query && $category):
        $criteria = $query_c->mergeWith($join);
    elseif ($query):
        $criteria = $query_c;
    elseif ($category):
        $criteria = $join;
    endif;
```

After $query_c->mergeWith($join) I was expecting $criteria to be a something like

```
 LEFT JOIN product_x_category as P_x_c ON (P_x_c.id = P.id)
 WHERE P_x_c.category_id = x
 AND (P.name LIKE '%query%' OR P.description LIKE '%query%')
```

But instead, I get $criteria == null...

What's going wrong here? Shouldn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the answer for your issue. But try to use following code. You can build the query using only one criteria.

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->alias = 'P';
    if ($query):
        $criteria->compare('name', $query, true, 'AND');
        $criteria->compare('description', $query, true, 'OR');
    endif;

    if ($category):
        $criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN product_x_category as P_x_c ON P.id = P_x_c.product_id';
        $criteria->compare('P_x_c.category_id', '=' . Category::model()->find('path=?', array($category))->id);
    endif;
```

Comment: Many thanks! May not be at the root of the issue, but still resolves my problem. By not using the mergeWith I sidestep the problematic step, and my code works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling across this, the root of the problem is that `mergeWith` doesn't return anything!

It updates the criteria that it is run from by merging in the properties of the criteria passed. The line:

```
$criteria = $query_c->mergeWith($join);
```

sets `$criteria` to `null` but `$query_c` is now the merge of `$query_c` and `$join`.

You would need something like this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();

if($query){
  $criteria->mergeWith($query_c);
}
if($category){
  $criteria->mergeWith($join);
}
```